# Matplotlib memory plotting loop

Tags: python, memory, matplotlib

Does anyone know why memory use keeps increasing? An idealised case is below, I can't see why.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


Lon = np.linspace(-180,180,1440)
Lat = np.linspace(-90,90,721)
Lon,Lat = np.meshgrid(Lon,Lat)


m = Basemap()
X, Y = m(Lon, Lat)
matrix = np.random.rand(721,1440)

for i in range(0,100):

    cs = m.contourf(X,Y,matrix)
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()
    print i
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the memory demand is accumulating due to the loop? Because if so, that's possibly not the error. `cs = m.contourf(X,Y,matrix)` on its own is ramping up the memory demand on my laptop until I kill the process fearing a freeze.

Comment: But the question is why would that continue to increase the use of RAM? First iteration uses a fair amount of ram, the point is it keeps on rising after each iteration

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May of been a memory leak - cannot replicate problem with the latest Matplotlib library.